# How to disable code analysis in Upsource

Tags: upsource

After upgrade from Upsource 2.0 to 3.0 it started to do code analysis on Java source files. Now it results in thousands of errors like:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'String'
Cannot resolve symbol 'java'
Cannot resolve symbol 'com'
...
```

We do not need code analysis at all. How to disable it? I cannot find this option in the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project's settings, find "Upsource properties", and set the "Build System" to "None". This'll turn it off. However it seems that it's just doing it wrong.